# Error with Imagick

Tags: php, web, imagemagick, imagick

I have a problem with Imagick. Imagick is correctly install (I can see it in my php.ini) but it does not work.

When I try to use the library in my PHP code, I have error.

Error is : ImagickException: UnableToOpenBlob `mypdf.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2642 in C:\wamp\www\testimagick\test.php on line 3

Here's my code :

```
<?php 
$myurl = 'mypdf.pdf[1]';
$image = new Imagick($myurl);
$image->setResolution( 300, 300 );
$image->setImageFormat( "png" );
$image->writeImage('newfilename.png');
?>
```

Thanks you !

Comment: It looks like you don't have a PDF file in the directory where your PHP is running. Try specifying the `full` path to it.

Comment: what is [1] in mypdf.pdf part ... is that the filename ?

Comment: `mypdf.pdf` and `test.php` are in the same directory. `[1]` part in `mypdf.pdf `means page 2. @Mark Setchell @rbawaskar

Comment: But are you running PHP from the command line or is it getting executed by a web server that runs from a different directory?

Comment: PHP is getting executed by Wamp/Apache Server

Comment: Try `new Imagick(realpath($myurl));`